# Google Chart API Control range and snapToData issues

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Using google charts API with line chart controlled by range finder.
I am stuck with two annoying issues:

1. The control has extra space before and after the data values it was set to follow, leaving an ugly space the control can slide to.
2. I can not seem to get the control to snap to data value.

If you can give me a pointer what I am doing wrong I will appreciate it a lot.
I set a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Db4fm/2/

Thank you very much!

### JS

```
function drawChart() {
var activity_breakdown = [
    ['Text Index', 'Numeric Index', 'totals', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 
     'Value 4', 'Value 5', 'Value 6', 'Value 7'],
    ['W15', 1, 13, 2, 0, 20, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    ['W16', 2, 20, 0, 1, 10, 3, 0, 0, 2],
    ['W17', 3, 19, 3, 0, 20, 2, 0, 2, 0],
    ['W18', 4, 31, 0, 2, 10, 4, 1, 0, 3],
    ['W19', 5, 11, 1, 0, 10, 2, 0, 3, 0],
    ['W20', 6, 26, 0, 0, 10, 6, 0, 0, 4],
    ['W21', 7, 39, 2, 0, 30, 2, 1, 2, 0],
    ['W22', 8, 41, 0, 3, 10, 7, 0, 0, 0],
    ['Today', 9, 44, 0, 1, 20, 2, 1, 0, 5]
];

// Data table
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(activity_breakdown);

// Chart
var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_activity',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
        width: 950,
        height: 300,
        chartArea: {
            left: 40,
            top: 20,
            width: 700,
            height: 250
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 13
            }
        }
    },
    view: {
        columns: [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }
});

var control1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control_activity',
        'options': {
        // Filter by the date axis.
        'filterColumnIndex': 1,
            'ui': {
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
                'snapToData': true, // this bugger is not working
            'chartOptions': {
                width: 950,
                height: 50,
                chartArea: {
                    left: 40,
                    top: 0,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 50
                },
                    'hAxis': {
                    textPosition: 'none'
                }
            },
                'chartView': {
                'columns': [0, 2]
            },
                'minRangeSize': 1
        }
    },
        'state': {
        'range': {
            'start': 7,
                'end': 8
        }
    }
});

var dashboard1 = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
document.getElementById('dashboard_activity'));

// Draw
dashboard1.bind(control1, chart1);
dashboard1.draw(data1);

google.visualization.events.addListener(control1, 'statechange', function () {
    var v = control1.getState();
    document.getElementById('dbgchart').innerHTML = v.range.start + ' -> ' +
    v.range.end;
    return 0;
});

// FSM knows why but without this line this line the code will not run...
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
}

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

### HTML

```
<div id="dashboard_activity">
    <div id="chart_activity"></div>
    <div id="control_activity"></div>
</div>
<p>Debug range: <span id="dbgchart">Init</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space before and after your data values is a result of setting your range filter's chart's domain axis to axis 0, which is a "string" type axis.  If you want the line to go edge-to-edge, the domain axis has to be a continuous data type ("number", "date", "datetime", "timeofday").  If you change the control's chart's `view.columns` parameter to `[1, 2]`, the spaces will go away:

```
var control1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_activity',
    options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 1,
        ui: {
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            snapToData: true, // this bugger is not working
            chartOptions: {
                width: 950,
                height: 50,
                chartArea: {
                    left: 40,
                    top: 0,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 50
                },
                hAxis: {
                    textPosition: 'none'
                }
            },
            chartView: {
                columns: [1, 2]
            },
                minRangeSize: 1
        }
    },
    state: {
        range: {
            start: 7,
            end: 8
        }
    }
});
```

I couldn't replicate your problem with the `ui.snapToData` option.

Updated jsfiddle with fix: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Db4fm/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot! About the snapToData there is nothing to replicate, the debug below shows the problem (or my misunderstanding of the property). If I understand correctly the increments should be 1, meaning the debug should show integers not floats. Can you advise?

Comment: When the slider is in motion, there is no way to make it move from one data point to the next without traversing the points in between (which shows up in your debug).  I think that in order to implement such a system, the slider would have to be "sticky"; that is, the end points would stick to data points and the user would have to drag the slider far enough to get the end points to unstick from the current data points and stick to the next data points.  I think that would be an unintuitive use of the slider, and could be potentially frustrating to users.

Comment: If you are interested in getting the state of the control and don't want to deal with the state when it is between data points, check the event's `inProgress` parameter, if true, the slider is in motion, and so you could ignore it.  Here's how it would affect your debug: http://jsfiddle.net/Db4fm/5/

Comment: You got my intent in the second comment and you did it SPOT ON! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 67 to as follows:

```
'columns': [1, 2]
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Db4fm/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I must rate based on first responder but I appreciate your time.